# Print out entire apache configuration for a particular directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

PHP, Postfix, and other applications have functions or flags (`phpinfo()` or `postconf -n`) to print out all the current configuration information. Apache has `mod_info` which can be enabled to print configuration information *to* a specific location:

```
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
<Location /server-info>
    SetHandler server-info
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 1.2.3.4
</Location>
```

However Apache configuration could change on a directory-by-directory basis, for instance with `.htaccess` files. How might one print out the entire Apache configuration *for a specific directory* including paths to all files used to make that configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try simply using a `<Files>` container:

```
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
<Files "server-info">
    SetHandler server-info
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 1.2.3.4
</Files>
```

That will make it so you can request for `server-info` in any existing directory. However, keep in mind some of the [mod_info limitations](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html#limitations):

> Configuration directives from .htaccess files are not listed (since they do not form part of the permanent server configuration).

Comment: Thank you Jon! How might one get the full configuration including directives from `.htaccess`? It is quite that which I need!

Comment: @dotancohen You can't do it through mod_info. It says so in the documentation. If you just want to see the contents of your htaccess file, you can just restrict access to it in the same way.

Comment: Right, thanks. The issue seems to be that there may be multiple `.htaccess` files in different parent directories and I'm not sure which directives are active. The first step of troubleshooting is to check the configuration, yet Apache seems to provide no way to do this.